# What happens when you close a .NET console application?

Tags: .net, console-application

Is a method such as `OnClosed(EventArgs e)` called?

**Update**

Ended up using code from the following url:

http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.clr/2003-11/msg00214.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article/post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/707e9ae1-a53f-4918-8ac4-62a1eddb3c4a).

Essentially, you hook up with the SetConsoleCtrlHandler and subscribe to the events.

Answer (score 1):

No, since there is no message pump for a close event.

However, the AppDomain is unloaded as the process is torn down, and this will fire [AppDomain.DomainUnloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx).  You can use that to trap an event as the program shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`AppDomain.ProcessExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) event that you could hook up an event handler to. Note thought that it is "time boxed"; by default it is allowed to execute for a maximum of 3 seconds, so you should not do anything time consuming in there.